# aiohttp and asyncio how to get response from http request and websocket in concurrent way?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I try to receive data from two endpoints in same time. But if websocket stop to send messages I won't receive data from request from `"https://www.blabla.com"`. What is the best way for solving this problem?

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

URL = 'wss://www.some_web_socket.io'

async def get_some_data(session):
    url = "https://www.blabla.com"

    async with session.get(url) as response:
        data = await response.text()
    return data

async def ws_handler(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.ws_connect(url) as ws:
            msg = await ws.receive()

            while True:
                some_data_from_get_request = await get_some_data(session)
                msg_from_websocket = await ws.receive()

                if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
                    print(stream_data)

                print(some_data_from_get_request)

def _main():
    asyncio.run(ws_handler(URL))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code serializes the return values of HTTP and websocket communication:

```
while True:
    some_data_from_get_request = await get_some_data(session)
    msg_from_websocket = await ws.receive()
```

To be able to detect either of the two coroutines returning, you can use `asyncio.wait(..., return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)`:

```
http_fut = asyncio.ensure_future(get_some_data(session))
ws_fut = asyncio.ensure_future(ws.receive())
pending = {http_fut, ws_fut}
while pending:
    _done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    if http_fut.done():
        some_data_from_get_request = http_fut.result()
        ...
    if ws_fut.done():
        msg_from_websocket = ws_fut.result()
        ...
```